# Skeleton is not a functorial construction

Tags: category-theory

How can I prove that there is no functor $sk(-): CAT \rightarrow CAT$, that sends a category to 'its skeleton'?

I mean by 'its skeleton' a skeletal category that is equivalent to $C$.

Edit: As a comment says, I know that skeleton defines a pseudo-functor; my question is about why it can't be restricted to define a functor.

Comment: $sk$ is a pseudofunctor, provided you can use the axioms of choice to choose an object in each isomorphism class. So, what exactly is the question here? To show that it can't be strictified?

Comment: @fosco Precisely that.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the skeleton construction, we can fix an object in each isomorphism class and fix isomorphisms $\varphi_b:b\to b_0$ to these fixed objects, and these determine the equivalence functor by sending $\beta:b\to y$ to $\varphi_y\circ\beta\circ\varphi^{-1}_b:b_0\to y_0$.

Then, for a functor $F:A\to B$ and arrow $\alpha:a_0\to x_0$ in ${\rm sk}(A)$ we have
$${\rm sk}(F)(\alpha)=\varphi_{Fx_0}\circ F(\alpha)\circ\varphi^{-1}_{Fa_0}\,.$$
Note that there's no interaction assumed between $F$ and the skeleton functors, i.e. $Fa_0$ need not be in the skeleton of $B$ even though $a_0$ is taken from the skeleton of $A$.

For simplicity of a counterexample, assume $A$ and $C$ are skeletonial categories, so all $\varphi_x$ are the identities for $x$ in $A$ or $C$, and consider functors $F:A\to B$ and $G:B\to C$.

We then have ${\rm sk}(GF)=GF$.

On the other hand, for an arrow $\alpha:a\to x$, consider the commutative square and its image under $G$.
$$\matrix{Fa&\overset{\varphi_{Fa}}\to&(Fa)_0\\ \downarrow&&\downarrow\\ 
Fx &\underset{\varphi_{Fx}}\to&(Fx)_0}$$
The point is that $G(\varphi_{Fa})$ and $G(\varphi_{Fx})$ can be *any* automorphisms $GFa=G(Fa)_0\to GFa$ and $GFx\to GFx$, so we obtain
$${\rm sk}(G)\,{\rm sk}(F)\,(\alpha)\ =\ 
G(\varphi_{Fx}\circ F(\alpha)\circ \varphi^{-1}_{Fa})$$
which might well differ from $GF(\alpha)$ by automorphisms on both ends.