# Do small skeletal categories form a reflective subcategory of the category of small categories?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{Cat}$ be the category of small categories and $\mathbf{SkelCat}$ be the full subcategory of small skeletal categories. Then, is $\mathbf{SkelCat}$ reflective in $\mathbf{Cat}$?

Note that the "skeletal reflection" of a category $C$ is not in general the same as a skeleton of $C$. For example, if $C$ is the "walking isomorphism" category with two objects $0$ and $1$ and an isomorphism $0 \cong 1$, then the "skeletal reflection" of $C$ is the group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition regarded as a single-object groupoid, which is not isomorphic to either of the two skeletons of $C$.

In fact, the categories $C$ that are "local" with respect to the class of equivalences (i.e. $\mathrm{Hom}(E,C) \to \mathrm{Hom}(D,C)$ is a bijection (ignoring natural transformations) for every equivalence $D \to E$) are precisely the "gaunt" categories, which satisfy a stronger property than skeletality. The only isomorphisms in a "gaunt" category are the identities, and this property obviously implies skeletality.

So, for a category $C$ containing no non-identity automorphisms, any skeleton of $C$ is a "gaunt" category and is in fact a "gaunt reflection" of $C$ (but not a "skeletal reflection" unless $C$ was already a "gaunt" (or equivalently, skeletal) category).

Comment: So, you've defined a functor $\mathbf{Cat} \to \mathbf{SkelCat}$ and called it "skeletal reflection." Are you asking whether it's adjoint to the inclusion $\mathbf{SkelCat} \to \mathbf{Cat}$? Why do gaunt categories come into play here? Do they help answer the question, or just give some intuition?

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4087366/skeleton-is-not-a-functorial-construction).

Comment: I think your computation of the skeletal reflection of $\{ 0 \cong 1 \}$ is not correct. As far as I can tell, the skeletal reflection is $1$. In general, a category with at most one isomorphism between any two objects (but arbitrary non-invertible morphisms) has a skeletal reflection that is isomorphic to its skeleton.